# Evaluation with Continuation Passing Style without the Cont Monad

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, expression-evaluation, continuation-passing

I have a task: to write a function `evalCPS` which evaluates expressions formalized by the ADT below, using Continuation Passing Style but without Cont Monad or similar stuff.

```
data Expr a = Expr a :+: Expr a
            | Expr a :/: Expr a
            | Num Int
            | Var a
            | Let a Int (Expr a)
```

I did it for the first three constructors, that's not so hard:

```
evalCPS :: Expr a -> (Int -> r) -> r

evalCPS (Num n) k = k n

evalCPS (e1 :+: e2) k =
   evalCPS e1 $ \n1 ->
   evalCPS e2 $ \n2 ->
   k (n1 + n2)

evalCPS (e1 :/: e2) k =
  evalCPS e2 $ \n2 ->
  if n2 == 0 then error "division by zero" else evalCPS e1 $ \n1 ->
  k (n1 `div` n2)
```

But now I'm stuck with `Var` and `Let` constructors. I think I kinda understand how to do this with monad, since I have bind operator in it, but I need an advice how to solve it directly, without using monads. Will be very thankful for help!

Comment: I think you need some kind of "environment" parameter, e.g. `rho :: a -> Int` to evaluate variables. You can also use a `Map` or association list, if you restrict `a` a little with a typeclass constraint.

Comment: Thanks for reply! Was thinking of something like this, but I don't get where I should define this `rho :: a -> Int t` I mean should it be something like:
`evalCPS (Var v) k = k . (env v) where
 env :: a -> Int`
or i misunderstood? I'm not able to change evalCPS function's type.

Comment: Without changing the type is more difficult. Perhaps you only need to handle closed terms, which define all the variables they use? If so, you could state `evalCPS (Let x n e) k = evalCPS (subst x n e) k` where `subst` is a kind of syntactic substitution helper. I'm unsure about what is the expected solution here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get yourself some sort of storage to store values for variables that get defined via `Let`. In the general interpreter/compiler terminology, such storage is usually called "environment". Let's define it this way:

```
type Env a = ...
```

Whenever you encounter a `Let`, you need to add a variable to the storage. Whenever you encounter a `Var`, you need to lookup the variable in the storage. Also, the whole computation should start out with an empty storage. This means that there should be three operations on storage:

```
emptyEnv :: Env a
lookupVar :: a -> Env a -> Int
insertVar :: (a, Int) -> Env a -> Env a
```

Now, your `evalCPS` function needs to take an `Env` as argument (otherwise how would it lookup variables?). This would be the environment in whose context the expression should be evaluated:

```
evalCPS :: Env a -> Expr a -> (Int -> r) -> r
```

The `:+:` case doesn't need to look at the environment, so it should just tunnel it through to the recursive `evalCPS` calls:

```
evalCPS env (e1 :+: e2) k =
   evalCPS env e1 $ \n1 ->
   evalCPS env e2 $ \n2 ->
   k (n1 + n2)
```

And similarly for the `:/:` case.

The `Var` case would lookup the variable value in the environment and just return it (by calling the continuation):

```
evalCPS env (Var a) k =
   k $ lookupVar a env
```

Simple enough.

The `Let` case has to construct a new environment by adding the new variable to the old one, and then evaluate the expression in the context of this new environment:

```
evalCPS env (Let a value e) k =
    let newEnv = insertVar (a, value) env
    in evalCPS newEnv e k
```

Still simple enough.

---

Now, how might we implement the environment itself? What should the bodies of `lookupVar`, `insertVar`, and `emptyEnv` look like?

Conceptually, the environment could be seen as just a function: you give it a variable identifier, it gives you back its `Int` value. From this understanding, the simplest possible implementation of the environment falls out:

```
type Env a = a -> Int
```

And from this, it is trivial to define `lookupVar`:

```
lookupVar :: a -> Env a -> Int
lookupVar a env = env a
```

`emptyEnv` is a bit trickier. Let's think: what should happen when the program tries to reference a variable that hasn't been defined? There is a wide range of possible answers to this question, but I will follow your lead and handle this error condition the same way you handle division by zero: simply call `error`:

```
emptyEnv :: Env a
emptyEnv _ = error "Undefined variable"
```

`insertVar` is trickier still. Let's think again: when I add a variable `a` with value `v` to an existing environment `e`, the result should be a new environment, such that if somebody tries to lookup variable `a`, the result should be value `v`. Let write that down:

```
insertVar :: Eq a => (a, Int) -> Env a -> Env a
insertVar (a, v) oldEnv = 
    \x -> if x == a then v else ???
```

And otherwise? Well, if somebody tries to lookup any variable *other* than `a`, the result should be the same as whatever `oldEnv` would give. Let's write that down too:

```
insertVar :: Eq a => (a, Int) -> Env a -> Env a
insertVar (a, v) oldEnv = 
    \x -> if x == a then v else oldEnv x
```

Simple enough. Note that, because I am using the comparison operator `==`, I had to add an `Eq a` constraint to the type signature. And since `evalCPS` tries to call `insertVar` at some point, the constraint would bleed into `evalCPS` as well:

```
evalCPS :: Eq a => Env a -> Expr a -> (Int -> r) -> r
```

This is only reasonable: if we want to be able to lookup variables in our variable storage, there has to be *some* way of telling which variable is which.

---

Of course, this implementation of `Env` has one crucial drawback: it effectively performs a linear search on every lookup, resulting in poor performance when there are a lot of variables. While this is ok for a toy exercise, this won't do for any serious compiler or interpreter.

If better performance is desired, feel free to experiment with other ways of storing the variable -> value mapping. For example, you might want to implement your storage as a `Map` (which offers logarithmic lookup times):

```
type Env a = Map a Int
```

I will leave the implementations of `emptyEnv`, `lookupVar`, and `insertVar` as an exercise.